# Selenium IDE testscript to Selenium IDE

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide

I have a question. Is there anybody here who could at least give me an idea or a video perhaps on how to create a test script from Selenium IDE, converting it into Selenium webdriver, setting it up in the visual studio and successfully running it. Your help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There are dozens and dozens of these videos already online. There is no point in using IDE. Go straight to webdriver. You must chose a language to write in first, C#,Java etc. If you don't know either of these, it's best to study these first and then move on to Selenium webdriver.

I suggest C#. You can use the Microsoft virtual academy to learn this from scratch.

Best of luck
-Aaron